# The tensor product of monads.

Tags: category-theory, monads

It is known that the tensor product of endofunctors *End(C)* over a given category *C* is given by composition and the category of monads *Mon(C)* over a given category is cartesian. That cartesian product is roughly described in *Monad Compositions I* (Manes and Mulry) for a given set-indexed family of monads $\mathbf{T_i}=(T_i,\mu_i,\eta_i)$ as $\mathbf{T}=(T,\mu,\eta)$ by the rules:

$\hspace{15em}{TX}=\prod{{T_i}X}$
   $\hspace{15em}{\pi_j\eta_X}=\eta_{jX}$
 $\hspace{15em}{\pi_j{(X\rightarrow{TY})}}={(TX\rightarrow{T_jX}\rightarrow{T_jY})}$
 $\hspace{15em}{\pi_j{(TTX\rightarrow{TX})}}={(TTX\rightarrow{T_jT_jX}\rightarrow{T_jX})}$

where I've omitted the name of the arrows.
Is there any reason for this product not to be a tensor product and hence the composition induced by the category *End(C)* where *Mon(C)* lives?

Remark: In my version of the paper the third rule was stated as

$\hspace{15em}{\pi_j{(X\rightarrow{TY})}}={(TX\rightarrow{TX_j}\rightarrow{TY_j})}$

which I guess is wrong.

Comment: So, you're asking why the cartesian product is not the same as composition? Well, one is commutative and the other isn't...

Comment: Right. However Mon(C) could be a symmetric monoidal cartesian category and then: cartesianproduct=tensor=composition. Is it the case?

Comment: No. Wishing for something doesn't make it true!

Comment: Nice phrase. So Mon(C) is endowed with a usual cartesian product (the one described above) and also the composition as tensor. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{Mon}(C)$ does not have composition as a tensor. The composite of two monads is not a monad in any natural way unless there is a [distributive law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_law_between_monads) between them. Lots of research goes into getting around this fact, e.g. the paper you cite.

For example, for any set $A$ there is a functor $\Delta_A: \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which is constant at $A$: it sends all objects to $A$ and all morphisms to $\mathrm{id}_A$. If $A$ has more than one element, then $\Delta_A$ does not admit a monad structure (this is a fun exercise). (It's also true that if $A$ has less than one element, then $\Delta_A$ does not admit a monad structure!)

Now let $T$ be a monad on $\mathsf{Set}$ such that $T(1) \neq 1$. Consider also the monad $\Delta_1$ which is constant at 1. We can compose the underlying functors $T\circ \Delta_1 = \Delta_{T(1)}$ to get the constant functor at the set $T(1)$. But this composite functor does not admit a monad structure.

Comment: Thanks. So we can define a new category, say DistMon(C), whose objects are monads such that for every pair of them we have a natural transformation in the form of a Distributive Law. Would DistMon(C) be a monoidal category?

Comment: A lot of arbitrary choices are required to define your "$\mathrm{DistMon}(C)$": as I've pointed out, there does not exist a distributive law between every pair of monads, so you'd have to arbitrarily choose to exclude some monads from this category. Moreover, there can in principle be more than one distributive law between two monads, so you'd have to arbitrarily choose one for each pair. Finally, you'd have to be extra careful if you want the composition product to be associative. So it's doubtful that this will work, and even more doubtful that the resulting category will be interesting.

Comment: If you're interested in higher categorical structures related to monads, you might want to look at [The Formal Theory of Monads](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404972900199), which I believe talks about the [bicategory of monads](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#the_bicategory_of_monads) in a bicategory (e.g. there is a 2-category of monads in $\mathsf{Cat}$). Your $\mathsf{Mon}(C)$ is recovered as certain 2-cells in this 2-category.

Comment: And a distributive law turns out to be a monad in the 2-category of monads!

Comment: The category of _Distributive Laws for monads_ is defined in _Monad Compositions I_ (Manes and Mulry) where the objects are couples of monads with a distributive law between them (and a dual construction for comonads).

Comment: Call it DistMon(C). What is remaining for me, however, is the existence and construction of a tensor product both in Mon(C) and in DistMon(C).

Comment: It sounds like you already know from Manes and Mulry that if  $C$ has (finite) products then $\mathrm{Mon}(C)$ has (finite) products, constructed in a straightforward way from those in $C$. Any category with finite products is monoidal under $\times$ (exercise!). Probably a similarly straightforward construction allows one to construct (finite) products in $\mathrm{DistMon}(C)$ from (finite) products in $C$. If you're really interested, you can try it out. Whether these particular monoidal structures are what you want, of course, depends on what you're trying to do...

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to ask another question since the whole thing is getting bigger.